# How to nest 2 SQL statements with a foreach loop inside each other

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, foreach

Okay I try with the first query to get all names of the computers from the table psComputers. Now I need in the second query a variable from the first query to iterate over all entries which are assigned to the respective computer in the table psTest. I wonder if such a thing is possible at all?

Table psComputer contains `ID`, `name`
Table psTest contains `ID`, `computername`, `category`, `value`

**index.php**

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM psComputers ");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row) {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        $statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM psTest WHERE computerName = $name");
        $statement2->execute();
        $result2 = $statement2->fetchAll();
        if ($statement2->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach ($statement2->fetchAll() as $row2) {
                $id2 = $row2['ID'];
                $computerName = $row2['computerName'];
                $category = $row2['category'];
                $value = $row2['value'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, since I'm guessing that `computerName` is a string, you need to quote the value: `computerName = '$name'`. You should actually look into using parameterized [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually injecting the value like that.

Comment: You could also to this in one single query, [using JOIN's](http://www.sql-join.com/).

Comment: Isn't `INNER JOIN` a better solution in the first place?

Comment: When you need to perform iterated queries, often there is a more intelligent way to query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes around `$name` in the second query, since it's a string.

```
$statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM psTest WHERE computerName = '$name'");
```

But since you're using a prepared query, you should use a parameter instead of substituting a variable.

You also shouldn't call `$statement->fetchAll()` twice. The first call will read all the rows, and the second won't have anything left to read (it doesn't reset the cursor).

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM psComputers ");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
if (count($result) > 0) {
    $statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM psTest WHERE computerName = :name");
    $statement2->bindParam(':name', $name);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $statement2->execute();
        $result2 = $statement2->fetchAll();
        if (count($result2) > 0) {
            foreach ($result2 as $row2) {
                $id2 = $row2['ID'];
                $computerName = $row2['computerName'];
                $category = $row2['category'];
                $value = $row2['value'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But even better is to just join the two queries:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT c.id AS computerID, c.name AS computerName, t.id AS testID, t.category, t.value
    FROM psComputers AS c
    JOIN psTest AS t ON c.name = t.computerName
    ORDER BY c.id");
```

Comment: A couple of issues... `PDO::rowCount` doesn't work for MySQL `SELECT` statements, and you can't do a second `fetchAll()` without calling `execute()` again (PDO has no way to reset the cursor). However given that the result set has already been saved into `$result`, you can substitute `count($result)` for `rowCount()` and `foreach ($result as $row)` for `foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row)`

Comment: @Nick The documentation says that `rowCount` might not work for some databases, but I think MySQL is one where it does work.

Comment: Comments on the man page suggest it might work with buffered queries on MySQL. But given that a `fetchAll` has been done already, may as well just use `count` on that array since that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Nick But I like your way better, I incorporated it. Although in practice I prefer `while ($row = $statement->fetch())` so we don't have to read the entire result into memory.

Comment: Absolutely agree on not using `fetchAll`, but when OP already has... who are we to disagree?! Although thinking about it a bit more, the `count` checks are redundant, just prepare `statement2` regardless, and change both `foreach` to a `while ... fetch()`

Comment: Anyway, since it now looks like I would have answered it... +1! :-)

Comment: Yeah, those row count checks are common. They can be useful if you have an `else` block that prints "No data found", otherwise they're not necessary because the loop will just stop immediately. But I long ago decided not to make a point of these little things.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things to note,

1. When using strings in queries, they must be quoted.
2. You are already preparing the statement - bind the value instead, and the note above becomes irrelevant.
3. You can use a `JOIN` instead of running a query in a loop. This will also remove the variable in the name, making both notes above irrelevant! (You should take note of both, but they become irrelevant for the code in question).

Its rarely a good idea to run a query within a loop.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pt.* 
                            FROM psTest pt 
                            JOIN psComputers pc ON pt.computerName=pc.name");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
if (count($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id2 = $row['ID'];
        $computerName = $row['computerName'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $value = $row['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Although `JOIN == INNER JOIN`, I advice suggesting `INNER JOIN` to new programmers for better readability and to avoid confusion. Anyway, it is always a good practice to keep the code more readable. Cheers! :)